# i want to add done button and return the date in textfiled in alertview controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

[actually i want this in objective c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuNVo.png)
i need some help for this type of code.
if any can help then proceed step by step.
i need done button and return date to text field.

```
[alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"date";
    textField.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;



}];
```

Comment: you need Done and reset button in top of date picker?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this complete example as you want.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate>{
    UIDatePicker *datepicker;
    UIToolbar *toolbar;
    UITextField *dateField;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    datepicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    datepicker.datePickerMode= UIDatePickerModeDate;
    datepicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIBarButtonItem *donebtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(setDate)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelDatePicker)];

    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelBtn,flex,donebtn, nil]];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)showAlertController:(id)sender {

    UIAlertController * alert= [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"Add Action"
                                message:@"Please enter notes or action"
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* save = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                   NSLog(@"Notes: %@", alert.textFields[0].text);
                                                   NSLog(@"Date: %@", alert.textFields[1].text);
                                               }];
    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                   }];

    [alert addAction:save];
    [alert addAction:cancel];

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Notes";
        textField.delegate = self;
    }];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Date";
        textField.delegate = self;
        [textField setInputView:datepicker];
        [textField setInputAccessoryView:toolbar];
        dateField = textField;
    }];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)setDate{

    NSDate *selectedDate = datepicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    dateField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedDate];

    [dateField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void) cancelDatePicker{
    [dateField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

**set**

```
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self;
```

**implement**

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)alertTextField {//add any method you want to execute to here. This method will be called when user taps on the textfield in alertview.
[ alertTextField resignFirstResponder];// to dismiss the keyboard.
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];//this is called on alertview to dismiss it.
}
```

**.h**

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

{

UIAlertView *alert;

}
```

**delegate**

```
alertTextField.delegate = self;
```

**yourMethod**

```
(void) yourMethod
 {

   alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"YourTitle" message:@"YourMessage" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Load",nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertController *alert;

//...

-(void)showAlertController {
    alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                message:@"Message"
                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *button = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
                                                       //Do your thing
                                                       //NSString *strTextField_1 = alert.textFields[0].text;
                                                       //NSString *strTextField_2 = alert.textFields[1].text;
                                                       //NSString *strTextField_3 = alert.textFields[2].text;
                                                   }];
    [alert addAction:button];

    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        [textField setPlaceholder:@"Notes"];
    }];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        [picker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
        [picker setTag:1];
        [picker addTarget:weakSelf
                   action:@selector(datePickerUpdated:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [textField setInputView:picker];

        [textField setPlaceholder:@"date"];
    }];
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        UIDatePicker *picker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
        [picker setMinimumDate:[NSDate date]];
        [picker setTag:2];
        [picker addTarget:weakSelf
                   action:@selector(datePickerUpdated:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [textField setInputView:picker];

        [textField setPlaceholder:@"date"];
    }];

    [self presentViewController:alert
                       animated:YES
                     completion:nil];
}
```

---

```
-(void)datePickerUpdated:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
    NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

    NSInteger currentIndex = datePicker.tag;
    [alert.textFields[currentIndex] setText:string];
}
```